# Jar made by gradle's jar task is not "fat" enough

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, spark-java

...obviously some necessary things are not included from the dependencies.
Once it reaches a call to an external library, it breaks, either with ClassNotFoundException, or without a word.

I started with [this skeleton project](https://github.com/mz0/kotlin-gradle-skeleton).
Relevant changes in `build.gradle`:

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'net.laca.FoKt'
}
```

(my main function is in fo.kt)

```
dependencies {
  //...
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation fileTree('libs') { include '*.jar' }
}
```

```
jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'csira'

 // Uncommend the last two lines to build a "fat" jar with `./gradlew jar`,
 //    and run it without Gradle's help: `java -jar build/libs/skeleton.jar`
  manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.laca.FoKt'  }
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

versions: Kotlin 1.4.20, Java 11, Gradle 6.7.1

Allegedly it should work this way. As it does if I start it with `gradle run`.
But when I start it with `java -jar build/libs/csira.jar` after `gradle jar`, it doesn't.

Relevant parts of `fo.kt`:

```
package net.laca

import spark.Spark.*
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  before("/*")
  { req, res ->
    res.type("application/json")
    println("hívás: ${req.requestMethod()} ${req.pathInfo()} " + req.queryString())
    println(GsonBuilder().create().toJson(req.queryMap().toMap()))    //line 14
    //...
  }
```

At GsonBuilder it breaks:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder
    at net.laca.FoKt$main$1.handle(fo.kt:14)
    at spark.FilterImpl$1.handle(FilterImpl.java:73)
    at spark.http.matching.BeforeFilters.execute(BeforeFilters.java:48)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:133)
    at ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 19 more
```

And when I take/comment out the 14th line, and it reaches a call to my own jar in `/libs`:

```
  get("/whatever")
  {
    println("before")
    com.zz.app.MyScalaClass.apply().myFun()
    println("after")
  }
```

then the last thing I see is `before`, the rest is silence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because your `jar` task is configured incorrectly. To understand why, look at your dependencies:

```java
dependencies {
  //...
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation fileTree('libs') { include '*.jar' }
}
```

You are using both the `compile` and `implementation` configurations. The former is deprecated and should not be used by the way.

Then look at the `jar` task:

```java
jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'csira'

 // Uncommend the last two lines to build a "fat" jar with `./gradlew jar`,
 //    and run it without Gradle's help: `java -jar build/libs/skeleton.jar`
  manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.laca.FoKt'  }
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

The `from` part instructs Gradle to collect all dependencies from the `compile` configuration only, and this will ignore the `implementation` configuration completely.

While you could change "compile" to "implementation" everywhere, the correct way to construct a fat jar is to actually collect from the `runtimeClasspath` configuration. This one extends other configurations like `compile` and `implementation`, but also `runtimeOnly` which you might find handy in the future.

There is actually also an example of how to do this in the [Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example). To adapt it for your project, it should look like:

```
jar {
  archiveBaseName = 'csira'

  manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'net.laca.FoKt'  }

  dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath

  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

The extra `dependsOn` line ensures that the `runtimeClasspath` configuration is completely resolved before trying to use it. Another difference is that it only collects jar files.

Comment: This is a great answer but I would improve it by adding a duplicatesStrategy a the jar task: `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN`

Comment: Yeah, got hit by that one myself when upgrading to Gradle 7.